Reading remote event logs, using c# .net core code, running on a linux machine
I'm using c# .net core 8.0 and I need to be able to read events from a remote windows event log and filter them by log name ("Security" in my case), event id and creation datetime. The thing is that this code should run on a linux machine. Is there a problem to use System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader and System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession?
And if there is, what can be the alternative?

EventLogReaderand is only available on Windows.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/384826/eventlog-is-not-supports-in-linux-using-net-core-3
This is not an answer, but an opinion.
A better approach would be to parse Linux log files or execute command codes to get a response.

My code is running on a linux machine but I need to get the event logs from a remote windows machine
